# using WireShark: how can I find the DLNA description xml for a device

Tags: wireshark, upnp, dlna

I'm trying to get my Wi-Fi speaker working on HomeAssistant.
For this I need the device.xml location.
I found a technical manual on the UPNP site describing the discovery of devices. The SSPD message should contain the location of the xml.
I installed Wireshark and connected to the speaker from my computer.
As a result, I get a packet that contains this

```
(øWW"l]öEÕN@@/
(
ÀîD+aÌZÕá|P´â¢/upnp/QPlaySCPD.xml</SCPDURL>
<controlURL>/upnp/control/QPlay1</controlURL>
<eventSubURL>/upnp/event/QPlay1</eventSubURL>
</service>
</serviceList>
</device>
</root>
```

I was expecting I could go to http://192.0.0.xx/upnp/QPlaySCPD.xml but that returns "Access Error: site or page Not found".
In wireshark I do see the xml file and it's content in the "reassembled TCP".

I'm not a network guy; I just fiddle until things work. Please see below for the packet; in the left column you see the XML I'm searching, in the right you see the frame.

[image: wiresharktrace]

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for reference, I found another wireshark packet containing  the url to the device.xml

so for my stereoboomm device it was ip:49152/description.xml